# ./Configure for non-boost ASIO

Tags: c++

I take a look inside the asio folder there are

- asio.manifest
- autogen.sh
- boost_asio.manifest
- boostify.pl
- configure.ac
- include/
- INSTALL
- src/  (there are asio_ssl.cpp and asio.cpp)

I didn't see any configure script where I can execute. How do I build this asio?
I read asio is a header only library.

So, what I can make out of those files in the asio folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you got it from a tarball, you should already have a `configure` script ready to be executed. If you checked from the repository, you probably need to run `./autogen.sh` to generate the `configure` script for you, using `configure.ac` as input.

The convention is:

- **./bootstrap**: it invokes **autoconf** to process `configure.ac` and spit out `configure`. Often it also invokes **automake** to process all `Makefile.am` files and turn them into `Makefile.in`. Many moons ago, the name `autogen.sh` was used instead of `bootstrap`. And `configure.in` was used instead of `configure.ac`.
- **./configure**: detects everything on the system and creates `config.status`, then executes it.
- **./config.status**: processes all `*.in` files into versions without the `.in` suffix. That includes `Makefile.in` -> `Makefile`. You don't have to run this script by hand.
- **INSTALL**: this **SHOULD** contain build instructions, such as "run `./autogen.sh` if you checked out a copy from the repository". Shame on the ASIO developers, they just point the user to look for a non-existing "doc" directory.

You need **autoconf** (and friends) installed to transform `configure.ac` into `configure`. Once that is done, the build system becomes self-contained. That is, you can do a `make dist-gzip` to pack all the sources (and the `configure` script), transfer the *tar.gz* it to another system, and follow from the `./configure` step, even if **autoconf** is not installed there.

Answer (score 0):

So, Here are the steps I've followed just now.

1. I went to http://think-async.com, which is the website that hosts the non-boost asio.
2. Their download link led me to sourceforge, and [version 1.4.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asio/files/asio/1.4.8%20%28Stable%29/asio-1.4.8.tar.bz2/download) of the software.
3. I then extracted the folder, and looking inside, I see the usual layout.
4. So the following steps include `./configure`, `make`, and probably `sudo make install`.